# SwiftUI How to adjust brightness of background color, and not all subviews

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I make it so the brightness only affects the view's background color and not its subviews? I want the text to stay white, but the background to get darker

this code

```
struct ListCell: View {
    let brightness : Double
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "music.house")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .padding()
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("List Name")
                        .padding(.bottom,5)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    
                    Text("A long subtitle which extends more than a line")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }
            }.background(Color.blue).brightness(brightness)
        }
    }
}
```

makes
[image: This happen]

and this code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var lists : [Listi] = theLists
    
    var body: some View {
        var color = 0.0
            List(lists) { list in
                ListCell(brightness: color).onAppear(perform: {
                    color -= 0.1
                })
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear
            })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

makes this happen
[image: makes this happen]

Comment: Try `.background(Color.blue.brightness(brightness))` instead of `.background(Color.blue).brightness(brightness)`

Comment: Yes, that seems to have worked, thank you.

Comment: I'll checkmark it if you want to post this as the answer.. Idk really how stack overflow works but I think you get credit of some kind.

Comment: Sure, thanks! There was a meta post about this a while ago, anyway: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253045/14351818

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do:

```
HStack {
 ... 
}
.background(Color.blue)
.brightness(brightness)
```

The order matters, so you can think of it as

1. HStack
2. HStack + **blue background**
3. HStack + blue background + **custom brightness**

... you're applying the brightness modifier to the `HStack + blue background`. Instead, if you only want the blue background to get the brightness modifier, just attach it like this instead:

```
HStack {
 ... 
}
.background(
    Color.blue
    .brightness(brightness)
)
```

[`Color`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color) conforms to [`View`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view), so you are allowed to add view modifiers like `brightness` to it.