# SwiftUI: Change Color brightness in gradient

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a gradient using the same color with a brightness modifier at one end. I tried this:

```
    let gradient = LinearGradient(
        colors: [Color.blue, Color.blue.brightness(0.1)],
        startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
```

Unfortunately this does not compile with the following error: `Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected element type 'Array<Color>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'Color')`

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64546711/swiftui-how-to-adjust-brightness-of-background-color-and-not-all-subviews) I would have expected it to work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use `brightness(_:)` modifier here. It returns `View` instead of `Color`.

If you want to add brightness to Color, you may need help from UIKit and need to implement as below.

```swift
extension Color {
    func adjust(hue: CGFloat = 0, saturation: CGFloat = 0, brightness: CGFloat = 0, opacity: CGFloat = 1) -> Color {
        let color = UIColor(self)
        var currentHue: CGFloat = 0
        var currentSaturation: CGFloat = 0
        var currentBrigthness: CGFloat = 0
        var currentOpacity: CGFloat = 0

        if color.getHue(&currentHue, saturation: &currentSaturation, brightness: &currentBrigthness, alpha: &currentOpacity) {
            return Color(hue: currentHue + hue, saturation: currentSaturation + saturation, brightness: currentBrigthness + brightness, opacity: currentOpacity + opacity)
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this.

```swift
LinearGradient(
    colors: [
        Color.blue.adjust(brightness: 0.5),
        Color.blue,
        Color.blue.adjust(brightness: -0.5),
    ],
    startPoint: .top,
    endPoint: .bottom
)
```

You can also use this initializer `Color(hue:saturation:brightness:opacity:)` for your custom color.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Only problem is when using this with colors from the asset catalogue it will always only pick up the light color variant even when in dark mode. Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 2):

The `brightness` modifier creates a view, not a color. A possible solution is to use Color with HSB initialiser, like below

```
let gradient = LinearGradient(
    colors: [Color.blue, Color(hue: 229/360, saturation: 0.98, brightness: 0.1)],
    startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
```

Comment: Here's an example for an existing `color` variable: 

`let rgbColor = NSColor(color).usingColorSpace(.deviceRGB)!`

        `let darkerColor = Color(hue: rgbColor.hueComponent, saturation: rgbColor.saturationComponent, brightness: rgbColor.brightnessComponent - 0.05)`